# Determining if a string contains a word

Tags: python, if-statement

In Python, what is the syntax for a statement that, given the following context:

```
words = 'blue yellow'
```

would be an if statement that checks to see if `words` contains the word "blue"? I.e.,

```
if words ??? 'blue':
    print 'yes'
elif words ??? 'blue':
    print 'no'
```

In English, "If words contain blue, then say yes. Otherwise, print no."

Comment: `if "blue" in words`.

Comment: Do you want "abluent" to print "yes" or "no"?

Comment: @DSM I was struggling to think of a word that didn't have blue as an obvious prefix or suffix ;) - nice one!

Comment: @DSM I think the other question already answered that but thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
words = 'blue yellow'

if 'blue' in words:
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

## Edit

I just realized that `nightly blues` would contain `blue`, but not as a whole word. If this is not what you want, split the wordlist:

```
if 'blue' in words.split():
    …
```

Comment: So basically you just flip it and put in.

Comment: So what the what now?

Comment: Lol well after your edit I read and that was not that case but ill keep that in mind. Oh and the comment I wrote made sense in my mind nvm about that lol.

Comment: I want it to say if it contains it at all. So I just write `if 'blue' in words`. Correct?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `in` or do explicit checks:

```
if 'blue ' in words:
    print 'yes'
```

or

```
if words.startswith('blue '):
    print 'yes'
```

Edit:
Those 2 will only work if the sentence doesnt end with 'blue'.
To check for that, you can do what one of the previous answers suggested

```
if 'blue' in words.split():
    print 'yes'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `regex`:

`\bblue\b` will return `True` only if it can find the exact word `'blue'`, otherwise `False`.

```
In [24]: import re

In [25]: strs='blue yellow'

In [26]: bool(re.search(r'\bblue\b',strs))
Out[26]: True

In [27]: strs="nightly blues"

In [28]: bool(re.search(r'\bblue\b',strs))
Out[28]: False
```

Comment: mmm... Thanks but seems complicated lol. I think ill just stick to `if 'blue' in words` but great answer!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is probably the following:

```
words = set('blue yellow'.split())
if 'blue' in words:
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

If your words list is really huge, you'll get a speed increase by wrapping `words.split()` in `set` as testing set membership is more computationally efficient than testing list membership.

Comment: Creation of set is an `O(N)` operation in itself, so this will help only if OP wants to check for membership multiple times on the same list and the list is huge.